# Let $P=\{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid f(x)>0\}$, $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. If $c\in P$, show that there exists a neighborhood $V_\delta (c)\subset P$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, and let $P=\{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid f(x)>0\}$. If $c\in P$, show that there exists a neighborhood $V_\delta (c)\subseteq P$.

Let $\epsilon >0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $c$, $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$ when $|x-c|<\delta $.

I'm not sure where to go from here, it seems like the idea is that since $f$ is continuous, any $x$ close to $c$ will result in $f(x)$ close to positive $f(c)$ and so must be positive itself.

Comment: please write your idea mathematically.. you are on the right path

Comment: But that's the problem I'm having. I don't know how to write it mathematically or where to go from there.

Comment: Take $\epsilon=f(c)$ and write what ever you have written for continuity of $f$ as definition...

Comment: Is that $z$ in the definition of P in there by mistake?

Comment: You have to basically prove that the inverse image of the set $(0,\infty)$ under $f$ is open.Does that help you get an idea?Look at the properties of continuous function with regards to a change in sign.

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea. You just needed to choose $\varepsilon$ appropriately.

If $c \in P$, then $f(c) > 0$. Let $\varepsilon = f(c)$, then by the continuity of $f$, there is $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(c)| < f(c)$ whenever $|x - c| < \delta$. That is, for $x \in V_{\delta}(c)$, $-f(c) < f(x) - f(c) < f(c)$ so $0 < f(x) < 2f(c)$. As $f(x) > 0$ for every $x \in V_{\delta}(c)$, $V_{\delta}(c) \subseteq P$.